# State is not updating immediately after onClick in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am clicking on checkbox. When I am checking the checkbox I am trying to update state but it is not updating immediately. I have created an onchange event named `handleAllCheckbox`.

Here is my code -
const [hello, setHello] = useState(false);

```
const handleAllCheckbox = (e) => {


    setHello(!hello);

    if (!hello) {
      contactList.map((item) => {
        Ids.push(item._id)
      });
      setTheArray(...theArray, Ids);
    }
    else {
      const newIds = []
      setTheArray(...theArray, newIds);
    }
  }
```

I want if `hello` is `true` then `theArray` must have Ids & if it is false then `theArray` should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `useEffect` if you want to handle any side effect, by side effect it means `do something when a particular state change`. So in your case probably can refer to below

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [hello, setHello] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!hello) {
    contactList.map((item) => {
      Ids.push(item._id)
    });
    setTheArray(...theArray, Ids);
  }
  else {
    const newIds = []
    setTheArray(...theArray, newIds);
  }
}, [hello]);


const handleAllCheckbox = () => setHello(!hello);
```

Notice `[hello]` as a second parameter of `useEffect`, it means `do something whenever "hello" state is updated`. So now your code is much cleaner as well, `handleAllCheckbox` only care about handling state `hello`, and whenever the value of `hello` being updated, `useEffect` takes care of that